# INSERT INTO SELECT Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I have query:

```
INSERT INTO zamowienia (id, wyslane, zdata, uwagi) 
SELECT   `id`, '0', '2016-01-22', 'TEST'  FROM TABLE
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.kid = TABLE.tid
WHERE name LIKE 'HOR' AND znumber LIKE '897'
```

If I try execute them, server return error:
Subquery returns more than 1 row

But, query:

```
SELECT   `id`, '0', '2016-01-22', 'TEST'  FROM TABLE
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.kid = TABLE.tid
WHERE name LIKE 'HOR' AND znumber LIKE '897'
```

returns only one row.

Why server return error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether there are any INSERT triggers on table `zamowienia`. The trigger may be causing this error.

Comment: That was a problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: hey, i know this is an old question, but i have the same problem. could you help me understand why an after insert trigger might be causing this error? thanks

Comment: In other words, it is not the top-level insert query that is causing the error. Rather, there is a trigger that fires on INSERT, that has its own query that is throwing the error. So look for triggers on the table you are inserting into. In a development environment, you can disable or remove the trigger to see if the problem goes away. If it does, you've found your culprit and can then dig deeper.